# How to filter date column data from sas with saspy (Python)?

Tags: python, sas, where-clause, saspy

I want to filter date column for a table

```
data = sas.sasdata("METEOGROUP", "ABC", "PANDAS", 
               {
                   "where": 
                   "DATE_DAY>'2021-04-20'"
               }
              ).to_df()
```

But there is no result from this query.
Without where clause i can see this dates.
How can i solve this problem?

DATE_DAY continues dates like this ; 2016-05-03

Comment: The string '2021-04-20' is not a date.  Dates are stored as numbers not strings. Did you try using a date constant instead of string?  '20APR2021'd

Answer (score 0):

In SAS, dates are filtered using what is called a date literal. It is of the form `'DDMMMYYYY'd`. For example, `'01JAN2022'd`. This automatically converts the string date into a SAS date, which is the number of days since Jan 1st 1960.

Here's an example of filtering sashelp.air to dates > March 1st 1955 and converting it into a pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import saspy

sas = saspy.SASsession()

data = sas.sasdata('air', 'sashelp', 'pandas', {'where': "date > '01MAR1955'd"}).to_df()

data.head()
```

```
        DATE    AIR
0 1955-04-01  269.0
1 1955-05-01  270.0
2 1955-06-01  315.0
3 1955-07-01  364.0
4 1955-08-01  347.0
```